# How to define multiple Azure TaskHub in host.json

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions, host.json

I want to have 2 Durable Functions, that would use separated TaskHub's (different configurations, storage, etc). It's possible to use TaskHubName in the Function declaration, so it must be possible to define them in host.json. Just can't find any example how?

```
"extensions": {
    "http": { "routePrefix": "" },
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "TaskHub1",
   ..
      "hubName": "TaskHub2",
```

I tried to pass array in durableTask, but it's expecting an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple task hubs in your `host.json` file by using the `durableTask` extension. refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp). Each task hub can have its own configuration, storage, and other settings.

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": [
      {
        "hubName": "TaskHub1",
        "storageProvider": "AzureStorage",
        "partitionCount": 16,
        "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 10,
        "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 10
      },
      {
        "hubName": "TaskHub2",
        "storageProvider": "AzureStorage",
        "partitionCount": 16,
        "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 10,
        "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 10
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

[image]

- Configured task hubs names as `TaskHub1` and `TaskHub2`. Each task hub uses the `AzureStorage` storage provider and has a partition count of `16`. The `maxConcurrentActivityFunctions` and `maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions` settings specify the maximum number of activity and orchestrator functions that can run parallel.

[image]

I can see that the function triggering both the storage accounts with different tasks assigned.

**store2azoct10:**
[image]

**azoct10:**
[image]